# Random variables with the same distribution which difference is positive almost surery.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$, $Y$ two random variables such that $P(X \le a)=P(Y\le a) \quad\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ (in other words, $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution). Suppose $X \le Y$ almost surely. Can I conclude $X=Y$ almost surely?

Comment: To show that it suffices to study the case when $X$ and $Y$ are integrable (bounded, even), note that the hypothesis implies that $X'\leqslant Y'$ and that $X'$ and $Y'$ have the same distribution, where $X'=\tanh X$ and $Y'=\tanh Y$. The end of the proof then makes use of the fact that if $X'=Y'$ almost surely then $X=Y$ almost surely, also direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ have finite expectation, you can, simply because

$$
\Vert Y - X\Vert_{L^1} = \int Y - X \, dP = E(Y)-E(X)=0. 
$$

Otherwise, apply the following **"truncation trick"**: Note that

$$
X_n = \min \{\max \{-n, X\} ,n \}
$$

has finite expectation for each $n$ (because it is bounded).

How does this help you?

Comment: min{max{-n,X},n}, perhaps?

Comment: @Did: Thanks for the comment. Fixed that. The "truncation/compression" idea using (e.g.) $\tanh$ you proposed  is very neat.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Let $Z=Y-X$, then by assumption $P(Z<0)=0.$ By linearity of the expectation, $$E(Z)=E(Y)-E(X)=0,$$and since $Z$ is non-negative almost surely, it follows that $P(Z>0)=0$.

Comment: If X and Y are integrable.